# How can I rewrite my Bluetooth Classic Arduino code into Bluetooth Low Energy Arduino code (and have everything working the same)

Tags: arduino-ide, bluetooth, esp32, ble

[My original code for BT Classic](https://0bin.net/paste/QTptCta3#8z3gLwP4LjhgVIPqd8DtE9MNHvtXJ+vZ6x6vIWv5+u0)

[My Work in Progress BLE Code](https://0bin.net/paste/90Z8nTYJ#aYBZ5NZB2rorubp2Ncsvj8HuQJFnxr8f5oDJJ4bMoBR)

I am trying to take all I did in BT Classic and have it working exacly the same in BLE but the Rssi keeps returning 0's in the BLE code and I don't get why, even after I do connect with my iPhone to the Esp32 the Rssi is still read as 0's.

In the BT Classic example everything works perfectly fine, but I am struggling to make my BLE code work.

What the first code does is reading Rssi signal from any device that connects to the Esp32, aproximating a distance based on the values and outputing the resulting Distance and Rssi in a list of pairs form via text that is sent to the other device, continously so that I can use that information to generate a graph and do various things with it.

I tried taking all I did in my BT Code and replicate it in BLE but it's not working at all, with rssi showing as 0 no matter what, and I've also read through the two Gatt Api's and tried replicating the same functions but there were some I didnt find an equivalent for in the BLE GATT Api:

https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-reference/bluetooth/esp_gap_ble.html

If anyone can guide me it'd be great. To make a summary, the first 0bin link represents the BT code I need to follow and the second 0bin link represents the BLE code I need to have it working just like the BT code (have it do the same exact things).